# parse comma separated data in java

Tags: java, csv

I need to parse the input data into 4 different parameters as in below format before calling the constructor to create the object. Any ideas?

sample data input format:

```
rawdata = "900,300,Ernest,Fuller\n777,555,Henry,Miller\n";     //and so on
```

.

```
class BaseRecord {

      int callerId;
      int areaId;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;

      BaseRecord (int cId, int aId, String fName, String lName)

                callerId = cId;
                areaId = aId;
                firstName = fName;
                lastName = lName;

}
```

Comment: Is that CSV data? or just a simple text file that happens to contain a few bits of data with commas?

Comment: Your raw data has 7 elements separated by 6 commas.  Which 4 do you want?

Comment: I think he first want to split the rawData in lines and then do the computation for each line.

Comment: @Volune, you're right, that didn't even occur to me...I looked right past those newlines.  Thanks!

Comment: @Marc B: this is not a csv file but a simple text file which happens to have commas as delimiter also every individual record is terminated with a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still not sure from the help given so far here is a little more. Split your raw data on the new lines. Then split each element of the resulting array to obtain the 4 parameters you're looking for. E.g.

```
String rawdata = "900,300,Ernest,Fuller\n777,555,Henry,Miller\n";

String[] records = rawdata.split("\n");

List<BaseRecord> baseRecords = new ArrayList<BaseRecord>();

for (String record: records) {
    String [] recordData = record.split(",");

    baseRecords.add(new BaseRecord(Integer.parseInt(recordData[0]), Integer.parseInt(recordData[1]), recordData[2], recordData[3]));
}
```

Now you have a list of BaseRecord objects. This assumes all the data is formed as presented in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Matcher` from `java.util.regex` package:

```
String rawdata = "900,300,Ernest,Fuller\n777,555,Henry,Miller\n";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\w+),(\\w+)", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(rawdata);
while(m.find()){
    int cId = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int aId = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    String fName = m.group(3);
    String lName = m.group(4);

    // your logic here
    new BaseRecord (int cId, int aId, String fName, String lName);
}
```

This way you can have multiple newlines and prevents the `NumberFormatException` on `parseInt`

Comment: Elias, this is a very good suggestion but I need a simple solution for now..I am not sure if I can import regex package only because we have restrictions on imports in prod :(

Comment: If you can't import `java.util.regex`, I'm really sorry for you. Even the java core class `java.lang.String` imports `java.util.regex` (verified in java 6, java 7, java 8), so I'm curious how and why you could have restrictions on this package.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = new String("a,b,c");
String[] split = s.split(",");
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It shows how to split a String into an array but he's got more data than he needs.

Comment: Well, once you get the array, you can extract the data by index and populate your object. E.g. `callerId = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);` and so on.